# how to JSON_EXTRACT using key from a column?

Tags: google-bigquery, json-extract

Bigquery JSON_EXTRACT function takes a string as the key to return the value. Is it possible to take the string from a column?

The `json_string_expr` to process is like `{'A': '123', 'B': '456'}`.
I want to take the key from a column `list`. 
The Bigquery table and expected result are as below.

```
   |   json_string_expr        | list   | expected_result
   |{'A': '123', 'B': '456'}   | A      |  '123'
   |{'A': '789', 'B': '012'}   | B      |  '012'
```

`JSON_EXTRACT(json_string_expr, '$.list')` couldn't give the expected result, because the function expects a string after `$.`.
Any idea how to return the expected result using standard SQL?

Comment: provide more examples of `json_string_expr` and `list` and expected output

Comment: oh, ok so list is actually not list(array) but rather string with just one item to be extracted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

Unfortunately, JSONPath must be a string literal or query parameter, so see workaround below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT json_string_expr, list,
  (SELECT SPLIT(kv, ':')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)]
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(json_string_expr, r"[{} ']", ''))) kv 
    WHERE SPLIT(kv, ':')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] = list
  ) value
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Another, less verbose version is

```
#standardSQL
SELECT json_string_expr, list,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(json_string_expr, CONCAT(r"'", list, "': '(.*?)'")) value
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

if to apply both above versions to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row json_string_expr            list    value    
1   {'A': '123', 'B': '456'}    A       123  
2   {'A': '789', 'B': '012'}    B       012
```

Comment: thanks, I tried the less verbose version. It works!